# Custom post type date output

Tags: wordpress, date, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type for contests.

and 1 of the fields is a closing date , everything is going fine only i cant figure out how to output the date format on the way i want it.

with this code in my loop i get the date , but not as ( day-Month-year )

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "_closingdate", array("format" => 'd m, Y'), true); ?>
```

the output remains year-month-day

i have searched everywhere to find a solution but i cant find it or i am overlooking something

Comment: Is this the way you have requested it to be formatted in the admin >> settings? If so, this will override your formatting.

Comment: yes it is indeed this format in the admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
echo date('d m, Y', strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID, "_closingdate")));
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do

```
echo date('d m, Y', get_post_meta($post->ID, "_closingdate"));
```

i dont know what type you used for this, but if timestamp from time() then its ready to use. If not - then you might have to parse it as string to date 1st then parse it to date.

Comment: Hi Seti , it's more or less working , i get the date as d m Y but all the date's are now the same 01-01-1970 :)

Comment: add  ,true  after  "_closingdate"